# Why imap_unordered has longer output than input when using pool with maxtasksperchild parameter in Anaconda python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, threadpool, python-multiprocessing

I have very function, with one argument, which is also return value. When imap_unordered is used with this function, its output is longer than iterable passed to imap_unordered. How is this possible? I use Anaconda python 3.6.5, while on standard python 3, this problem is not present.

Here is code of whole script:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def func(i):
    return i

iterable = [i for i in range(20)]
counter = 0

with Pool(4,maxtasksperchild=2) as p:
    for out in p.imap_unordered(func,iterable):
        counter += 1
        print(counter)
```

And now the output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

Why the numbers are not lineary growing in output? (look at `9,10,9,10`, should be `9,10,11`)

Firstly, i thought that problem is with imap_unordered function, as it does not returns its output ordered, but thats not true, because the script does not print output of mapped function, but just prints value of counter variable, which should be increased by 1 each time in loop. It's just normal loop where some variable is increased by 1 after each iteration.

Well, when `maxtasksperchild` argument is not used, then output is correct.

Does anybody know why this behavior is present when using `maxtasksperchild`?

Comment: I actually can't reproduce this, and I can't see how it would happen. This only makes sense if `counter` is being incremented from within different processes at the same time. I can't see how that would happen here though. Unless `with Pool` runs its body in separate processes? I don't think it would/can though.

Comment: @Carcigenicate unfortunately there is no other process which could manipulate this variable...